# Failed to resolve gradle dependency from GitHub packages in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, github-packages

I have created a Kotlin multiplatform module which I am now trying to add as a dependency to my Android project. I have published the module to GitHub packages. When I try to sync the Android project I get the following error:

`Failed to resolve: com.example:package:version`
Where com.example is the group, package is the artifact id and version is the version.

The dependency looks like this in the build.gradle for the module in my project which depends on it

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven {
    name = "GitHubPackages"
    url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/[account-name]/[repository-name]")
    credentials(PasswordCredentials)
  }
}
dependencies {
  implementation project(':expo-modules-core')
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${getKotlinVersion()}"
  implementation "com.example:package:version"
}
```

I have tried to find the cause of this problem but I am not familiar enough with Android Studio or Gradle to get any useful diagnostic information.

I believe that authentication with GitHub packages is working correctly since if I try setting an incorrect value for the access token I start getting authentication errors.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me to identify the source of this problem.

Comment: Gradle is trying to find this dependency "com.example:package:version"  in the repo you mentioned, but it's not able to find it. Is that the actual dependency or you were supposed to change it to the actual one?.

Comment: I have replaced the real values with "com.example:package:version". Every indication I have leads me to believe that the dependency is in the repo but I am not very familiar with maven.

Comment: When I make a request to: https://maven.pkg.github.com/[account-name]/[repository-name]/com.example/package/maven-metadata.xml I get the following reply:  com.examplepackage1.3.31.3.21.3.320231130142133
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<metadata>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>package</artifactId>
<versioning>
<latest>1.3.3</latest>
<versions>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<version>1.3.3</version>
...
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20231130142133</lastUpdated>
...
</versioning>
...
</metadata>

Comment: This leads me to believe that the package is in the repository but is there another way of confirming this?